# Class constraint in trait not working

Tags: symfony, validation, constraints, traits

I've got a simple entity type "City"

```
class City
{

    use GeoTrait;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    ...

}
```

as you can see it uses a Trait, which looks like this

```
use AppBundle\Validator\Constraint as AppConstraint;

/**
 * @AppConstraint\IsDuplicateLocation
 * @AppConstraint\IsLocation
 */
trait GeoTrait
{
         /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="geoLat", type="decimal", nullable = true, precision=9, scale=6)
    */
   private $geoLat;
   /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="geoLng", type="decimal", nullable = true, precision=9, scale=6)
    */
   private $geoLng;
}
```

Now, if i create a new entity and try to vaildate it using the validator service, it doesn't seem to validate my custom class constraints.

If i add a field constraint to the trait the validation is working fine, but not for the class constraint. Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Trait is not a class, so you can't target it in your custom Constraint "getTargets()" method.

Try adding your class constraints to the City class

```
/**
* @AppConstraint\IsDuplicateLocation
* @AppConstraint\IsLocation
*/
class City
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: that's working if i create a new entity with a form. But if i use the validator service as in this example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#using-the-validator-service there are no errors (allthough there should be)

Comment: @casper It should work. I just tested it. Post one of your constraints and its validator code so we can analyze it.